# Creating Logout routes for Laravel 9.0x

Tags: php, laravel

I can't make the logout link work for my simple laravel project. The user needs to login first before going to the dashboard, so I created a route that gets the **{id}** of the logged in user. and I think thats the reason the page just refreshes and does not logout and redirect to the login page. Ill provide the codes and snippets below.

**Web.php file**

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{id}',[CustomAuthController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/logout', [CustomAuthController::class, 'logout']);
```

**Blade.php file**

```
 <div class="row" >
  <div class="col-12">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
     <nav class="breadcrumb">
      <a class="breadcrumb-item active " href="dashboard/{id}" >Dashboard</a>
      <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="about-us">About us</a>
      <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="products">Products</a>
      <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="contact-us">Contact Us</a>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <li>
  <a href="logout" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-danger"  style="float:right;">Logout</a>
 </li>
```

**Here is the link whenever i click the logout button**

http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/logout

**Controller.php file for logout**

```
    public function logout(){
        if(Session::has('loginId')){
            Session::pull('loginId');
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

I tried googling other solutions but with no success. You might know some links I can read about or additional Laravel documentations. Thanks

Comment: any reason you are not using the default auth system? also you are using relative paths for your links ... and why would you need to pass an id in the URL for the dashboard route?

Comment: haven't tried it yet. i'm just following a tutorial in youtube.

Comment: because if i didnt include the id in the dashboard route it will return a 404 not found

Comment: you might wanna show me the answer so that i can improve my routing and methods, thank you in advance

Comment: If YouTube is teaching you to build your own custom authentication systems as a beginner, you should find a different tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using relative links to logout is easy, it falls more vulnerable to XSS. Switching over to a post route for logout like:

```
Route::post('/logout', [CustomAuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

And changing your logout button to include a CSRF token

```
        <li>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                @csrf

                <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-danger"
                        style="float:right;">
                    Logout
                </button>
            </form>
        </li>
```

This adds an extra layer of protection

Answer (score 0):

you're logout link is wrong change it from `href="logout"` to `href="/logout"` since its relative it has been trying to reach `/dashboard/logout` which is incorrect since the routing you've set is under `/logout` so it has only been redirected back to dashboard because of this